# Vlookup with multiple criteria with returned array inserted into ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Is there a way to use VBA to Vlookup with multiple criteria and then have those multiple returned values then inserted into a ComboBox? For the table below, I would like to have "Marlins" as the search criteria, and then have {RBI, Score, ABV} inserted into a ComboBox as options. Is this possible?

**Example Data:**

| Identifier | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Pirates | Score |
| Marlins | RBI |
| Marlins | Score |
| Marlins | ABV |
| Pirates | HRS |

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Marlins", Worksheets("Metadata").Range("A2:B5"), 2, False)
```

Comment: Instead of VLookUp, you might have more success looping through the data and gathering the values into an array. Once you have the array, you can easily insert the values into the ComboBox like `ComboBox.List = MyArray`

Comment: @Toddleson any chance you might be able to post an example script? Still at the beginner-level VBA proficiency.

Comment: There are many great tutorials on how to Loop through ranges and look at worksheet values. I don't think any answer I can put here would be nearly as good as the professionally written tutorials you might find elsewhere on the internet. The specific pieces you'd be looking to learn about would be `For ... Next Loops`, `Range Objects`, `If Statements`, and `Arrays`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Populate a ComboBox

**A Simple Example**

```vb
Sub PopulateComboBox()
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Metadata")
    
    ' Write the values of the range to a 2D one-based array.
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = ws.Range("A2:B5").Value
    
    ' Write the unique values from column 2, where column 1 is "Marlin",
    ' to the keys of a dictionary.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(sData, 1)
        If StrComp(CStr(sData(r, 1)), "Marlin", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
           dict(sData(r, 2)) = Empty
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Write the values from the keys of the dictionary to the combo box.
    With ws.ComboBox1 ' active-x combobox on the worksheet
        .Clear
        If dict.Count > 0 Then .List = dict.Keys
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go +:) - Side note: `.Clear` will be redundant if there are existing keys in the dictionary as the `.List` assignment overwrites all Combobox values anyway. So you may enclose it in a condition. For version MS365 you could try my filtering approach below. @VBasic2008

Answer (score 3):

If you dispose of the newer dynamic array features of vers. MS365,
you might profit from the following function `filtered()`

- (a) returning an evaluated **`Filter()` formula string** (based on results of help function `MakeFormula` and
- (b) checking for possible non-findings

```
Function filtered(data As Range, Optional ByVal criteria As String = "Marlins")
'a) Return filtered data as 1-based 2D array.
    filtered = data.Parent.Evaluate(MakeFormula(data, criteria))
'b) (Provide for possible non-findings via Error check).
    If IsError(filtered) Then filtered = Array(Empty)
End Function
```

*Help function `MakeFormula`*

```
Function MakeFormula(data, ByVal criteria As String) As String
'0. Get Column addresses.
    Dim critAddr$: critAddr = data.Columns("A").Address(0, 0)
    Dim valsAddr$: valsAddr = data.Columns("B").Address(0, 0)
'1. Return concatenated formula - e.g. "FILTER(B2:B6,A2:A6=""Marlins"")"
    MakeFormula = "FILTER(" & valsAddr & "," & critAddr & "=""" & criteria & """)"
End Function
```

**Example call**

It suffices to pass the entire data range as parameter (and/or an optional criteria, e.g. "Marlins").

*Note that you don't need to clear the combobox values as the whole `.List` property
gets (re-)assigned by the *filtered* values.*

```
Sub ExampleCall
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Metadata")
    ' Assign the filtered data to the combo box´es .List property.
    With ws.OLEObjects("ComboBox1")
        .Object.list = filtered(ws.Range("A2:B6"))
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the ActiveX ComboBox, and let the default name as ComboBox1.

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim cell As Range: dim crit as string

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .ComboBox1.Clear
    End With

crit = "Marlins"

    With rg
        .Replace crit, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
             For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, 1)
                ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
             Next
        .Replace True, crit, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    End With
    
End Sub
```

The code assumed that your data exactly the same as in your image attachment.
So, the Identifier header is in cell A1 where it's data starts from cell A2.
And the Value header is in cell B1 where it's data starts from cell B2.

The process:
It make a range for the Identifier data as variable rg.

create variable crit with value "Marlins".

Then within the rg, it replace all rows which contains text "Marlins" with logical TRUE, get the range of the cell which contains "TRUE" offset(0,1), do the loop to put each looped cell value as the ComboBox1 item, bring the TRUE value back to "Marlins".

The sub must be run where the sheet of your data is active.